# Painted Edges With with transparent background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I'm using Photoshop CS6 and I wanted to turn a photo I had to look like it had a painted edges effect.  I've been following the below tutorial and using a painted edges overlay over my picture, but I would like the background to be transparent instead of choosing a solid colour.

https://youtu.be/b9epx4EjYS0?t=175

I've tried a few things, but it either results in the background being white or the main picture looking like it's slightly transparent and no the full colour.

Can anyone help with any simple techniques to achieve this?  I want it to look like the below but instead of a white background a transparent one.

[image: brushed edges]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the layer mask to the image itself. If there's still a problem with the layer mask not being fully white or fully black, then select the layer mask and apply a levels adjustment to the mask to increase the contrast.

For example:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that the mask is used on a solid color above the background image instead of on the image itself, as you show here.

Comment: @Wolff, maybe. But I assume the OP at least knows the basics of masking and should be able to work it out from my screenshot. I'll add a little edit to mention it though.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr that's exactly what I needed.  All working now :)